# Создание файла базы данных Firebird

Tags: golang, firebird

Использую firebirdsql, но похоже с помощью данной библиотеки невозможно создавать саму базу. По крайней мере

```go
db, err := sql.Open("firebirdsql", "sysdba:masterkey@localhost:3050/D:\\test.fdb")
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("Opening error", err)
  return
}

if _, err := db.Exec("create table mytable user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey' page_size 8192  default character set win1251"); err != nil {
  fmt.Println("DB failure", err)
  return
}
```

всегда схлопывается на "DB failure". Может я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Table <> Database. Синтаксис проверяй хотя бы в isql.